# How to implement something like below?

Tags: flash

[Here](http://www.lenovo.com/us/en/smallerbiggerbetter/)

[Ed. warning: full screen flash site with music]

Comment: Are you talking about the parallax effect in the page or the animated preloader...or something else...

Answer (score 2):

With Flash, Actionscript, and a touch of skill.

EDIT* also Photoshop & Nunchuck skills.